# For a surjective function $f:G\rightarrow H$, if $f(a)=f(b)$, does it follow that $a=b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am wondering the question in the title. What I understand about surjectivity is that if a $f$ is surjective (onto), then for all $h\in H$, there exists some $g\in G$ such that $f(g)=h$. I also know that $H$ is "bigger" than $G$ provided that $f$ is surjective.

Can someone please clarify this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider the example $G=\{0,1\}$, $H=\{0\}$, and $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Comment: H is not necessarily bigger, it could be "the same size" as G. Also, the definition you gave is injectivity, which is not the same and not provable by surjectivity alone.

Comment: Absolutely not.  Injective ($f(a) = f(b)$ implies $a=b$) and surjective are two different properties of functions.  A function can be injective, surjective, both, or neither.

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ with $B = \{b\}$ a singleton and $A$ containing more than one element. This function is constant so $f(a_1) = f(a_2)=b$ for any $a_1, a_2 \in A$ even if $a_1 \neq a_2$ and is clearly surjective.